# as3 show privacy panel without tabs

Tags: actionscript-3, security, panel, microphone

we  are working  on  an  application  that use a microphone.
We would  like  to show the  the privacy settings panel, but  without  the  tab microphone, camera etc,  just  the basic privacy panel.

Here the picture to make everything  clearer:

SETTINGS WITH TAB

http://www.creativewave.it/settings_tabs.jpg

SETTINGS WITHOUT TAB

http://www.creativewave.it/settings_notabs.jpg

We  know  the if  we  use

mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
 mic.setLoopBack(true)
we  can have it.
The problem is that in this way the  user hear  his voice when  speaks at  the microphone,
and it's horrible for our application.

And if  we use:
 Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY); 
we  get  the  privacy  panel, but with  the  tabs.

Is  there  anyway  to have SETTINGS WITHOUT TAB panel but WITHOUT using  setLoopBack(true)?

Alternatively, is there  a real way  to use  setLoopback(true) but  without having  the  echo  of the  own voice? we did try A LOT of things for  that  but really without  success.

thanks a lot.
Paolo

Comment: couldn't you just mute the audio while the box is up?

Comment: added it as an answer so you can accept it if it worked to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the volume of the mic to 0 using soundTransform & later increase it...

```
var st:SoundTransform = mic.soundTransform;
st.volume = 0;
mic.soundTransform = st;
```

Comment: Yeah,  I  did  try it, but they  it didn't seem to work. Thank's   a lot anyway.

Comment: micSelected = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone( selectedMicIndex);
micSelected.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, micStatusHandler);
micSelected.encodeQuality = 5;
micSelected.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
micSelected.rate =16;
micSelected.framesPerPacket = 1;
micSelected.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
var transform1:SoundTransform = micSelected.soundTransform;
transform1.volume = 0;
micSelected.soundTransform = transform1;
micSelected.setLoopBack(true);

Comment: hi,  well,, i didnt't  really know  why  was  not working. That was  is the code i used for trying it.

for the moment  I used  a solution  very  close to the  one on LondonDrugsMediaService. If you  know  what is  the problem it can be stell useful for  another task. Thanks  a lot Paolo

Answer (score 0):

Try muting the global audio right before calling Microphone.getMicrophone()  Then turn the volume back up after the privacy box has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use Security.showSettings("2"); you will get what you want